# Reference a function in the same object using Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I've got a JS object that looks like so:

```
return {
  foo: function() {
    return this.bar();
  },

  bar: function() {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Why do I keep getting a `TypeError: this.bar is not a function` logged in FireBug? What's the proper way to reference the `bar()` method from `foo()` in the same object?

## Update

So I've posted a fiddle with the whole code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4ghuq/). The return call is actually part of a RequireJS `define`. Let me know if any further clarification is required.

Comment: can you please provide a fiddle for that? it works in Chrome.

Comment: `this` depends on how you call it.

Comment: Can you post some more code, i.e. the function where this return is included, and the invocation calls you are using?

Comment: can you provide more sample code?

Comment: @Lean: done: http://jsfiddle.net/4ghuq/

Comment: @deceze: It's part of a RequireJS `define` call. JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4ghuq/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how it is called; If for instance `theObject.foo` is passed as callback to another function (e.g. `jQuery(x).on("click", theObject.foo)`), the `this` context will probably be lost.

A way to enforce that `bar` calls `foo` is to make a closure. Change the function that returns the object as:

```
function thatReturnsTheOject() {
    var ret = {
        foo: function() {
            return ret.bar(); // <---- Using `ret` not `this`
        },
        bar: function() {
            return 1;
        }
    };
    return ret;
}
```

---

Another way, more complex but may result in a more familiar language usage is this:

```
function thatReturnsTheOject() {
    var ret = {};

    ret.foo = (function() {
        return this.bar(); // <---- Using `this` again
    }).bind(ret);          // <---- but note the `bind()`

    ret.bar = function() {
        return 1;
    };

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Do you know of a way to force the reference to bind to the same object (kinda like `self` in PHP)?

Comment: You mean when you use the reference? E.g. do `jQuery(x).on("click", theObject.foo)`, use `this` in `foo()` and still reference the correct object?

Comment: No, i mean within the object itself. Is there a keyword I put in place of `this` to mimic the functionality i'm looking for?

Comment: No, there is no such thing. You could do something that looks familiar: name the returned object `self` instead of `ret`, so you can use `return self.bar();`. Still this is only a game of words, not a solution as the one you are asking. See the edit using `Function.bind()`, but I doubt it is really better...

Comment: Your answer works great. I'm just being inquisitive. Thanks old chap!